# How to know which letters in hangman the user guessed and how to store them in the final list accordingly to their index in the secret word

Tags: python

I am posting for the first time on Stackoverflow and I don't know if I am doing this the right way, but I am looking to store all letters that the user guessed in a list and if the list is equal to the word, the user wins.
thanks :)

CODE :

```
word = "apache"

word_list = [x for x in word]

print("The word is ", "_ " * len(word))
final = []

while True:
    guess = input("Your guess : ").lower().strip()
    if guess.isalpha() and len(guess) == 1 or len(guess) == len(word):
        if guess == word or final == word_list:
            print("Good joby you have guessed the word!")
            break
        elif guess in word:
            final = "".join(x if x in guess else "_ " for x in word_list)
            print("".join(final))
        elif len(guess) == len(word) and guess != word:
            print("Sorry mate, wrong word")
        elif guess not in word:
            print("Wrong guess")
    else:
        print("\nYou need to either enter a word of the same length or a letter\n")
```

---

This is the bug I get :

Your guess : a,
a_ a_ _ _ 
Your guess : p,
_ p_ _ _ _ 
Your guess : c,
_ _ _ c_ _ 
Your guess :

It won't store all the letters I guessed before but only the letter I  just recently guessed

Comment: `final = "".join(x if x in guess else "_ " for x in word_list)` overwrites whatever final had earlier.

Comment: Can't you just append the guesses to a list then check if the guess already exists in the list?

Comment: Should you not store all letters that have been guessed, including those that are wrong? After all, guessing the same letter twice should not penalize you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is as @Paritosh Singh said you overwrite final. You are also declaring final as a list and overwrite it with a string (which is legal in python). final is probably a string and you need to update it not overwrite it :

```
word = "apache"

word_list = [x for x in word]

print("The word is ", "_ " * len(word))
final = ""

while True:
    guess = input("Your guess : ").lower().strip()
    if guess.isalpha() and len(guess) == 1 or len(guess) == len(word):
        if guess == word or final == word_list:
            print("Good joby you have guessed the word!")
            break
        elif guess in word:
            final = "".join(x if x in guess or x in final else "_ " for x in word_list)
            if final == word:
               print("Good joby you have guessed the word!")
               break
            else:
               print(final)
        elif len(guess) == len(word) and guess != word:
            print("Sorry mate, wrong word")
        elif guess not in word:
            print("Wrong guess")
    else:
        print("\nYou need to either enter a word of the same length or a letter\n")
```